# Composer not getting the most up to date version with wildcard

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a Composer package that requires OtherPackage vs 1.0.*.  I know that version 1.0.3 exists, but it keeps downloading version 1.0.1.  I can't figure out why it is not getting the latest version.

my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
   "MyVendor/OtherPackage": "1.0.*",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out because I tried to force version 1.0.3 and got the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

    - Installation request for myVendor/OtherPackage 1.0.3 -> satisfiable by MyVendor/OtherPackage[1.0.3]
    - MyVendor/OtherPackage 1.0.3 requires OtherVendor/ThirdPackage 1.0.1 -> no matching package found.
```

So that's when I remembered that MyVendor/OtherPackage 1.0.1 didn't have the ThirdPackage dependency, while 1.0.2 and 1.0.3 did.  I didn't include ThirdPackage in my composer.json requirements.  As a result Composer was smart enough to get the latest version of OtherPackage that was satisfiable for all of my current dependencies.

My solution was just to add OtherVendor/ThirdPackage 1.0.1 to my requires declaration in composer.json.

My new composer.json

```
"require": {
   "MyVendor/OtherPackage": "1.0.*",
   "OtherVendor/ThridPackage":"1.0.1"
},
```